# How do I access files, copy them on an external hard drive, and see them on it?

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, mount, single-user

I'm trying to recover the password of an old iMac, couldn’t boot to Recovery though. So I went into single user mode to access the files, which worked. I have an external hard drive that is formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) to put the files I'm looking for on the iMac into the drive. I copied them and I went to my computer to access it. But now my drive isn't mounting!

When I did the copy I ran the command `cp <file> /dev/disk1s2`. When I try to mount it on the other computer to see the files, I tried mounting it through the command line with `diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2` and `diskutil mount /dev/disk2s2`. Both commands gave me an error saying that the disk failed to mount. I also tried mounting it through Disk Utility but nothing happens.

I need those files because it contains the password of the computer. How am I going to see the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `cp` destroyed whatever filesystem there was on the external disk because you copied to the device itself without mounting it first. To fix:

- format the external disk on the other Mac (HFS+ should be fine)
- boot old Mac into single user
- mount the external disk (`mkdir /Volumes/mydisk; mount /dev/disk1s2 /Volumes/mydisk`)
- copy the files to the mounted disk (`cp files /Volumes/mydisk/`)
- unmount disk before unplugging (`umount /Volumes/mydisk`)

Comment: Single user mode won't let me use diskutil in single user mode. The warning says `Unable to run because unable to use DiskManagement framework. Common reasons include, but are not limited to, the DiskArbitration framework being unavailable due to being booted into single-user mode`

Comment: @MatthewSchell You can also just use `mount` then

Comment: Even after running /sbin/mount -uw, the filesystem is read-only. Can't create directory

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/en-is/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac) to copy the files to a location that's available on your working computer, eg. a properly formatted & mounted external drive.

Comment: Actually, I don't have a thunderbolt cable

Comment: @MatthewSchell are you on macOS 11.1.x Big Sur?

Comment: No, the iMac with the account I want to recover the password for has Mac OSX 10.6.8 and the other macbook that I want to use to recover the password for the iMac is macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: @MatthewSchell then you don't need a thunderbolt cable

Comment: How would I connect it then? By USB Cable?

Comment: 1. Connect the two computers with a FireWire or Thunderbolt cable. - https://support.apple.com/en-is/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac